# How to include external file with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

**Is it possible to include external file with webpack (outside the context) and make the file included in built output bundle.js?**

consider this setup where "sub-app" is context for webpack:

- /sub-app/entry.js
- /bower-components/zepto/zepto.js

And webpack config with broccoli:

```
var webpackify = require('broccoli-webpack');
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");

var bundler = webpackify(path.resolve('sub-app'), {
    entry: './entry',
    output: {filename: './bundle.js'},
    devtool: 'eval',

    module: {
      loaders: [
        {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
        {test: /\.hbs$/, loader: "handlebars-loader"}
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ]
});
```

**I would like to include zepto.js in output bundle.js. But I need to preserve bower_components outside the sub-app.**

Comment: Similar question with different answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151194/how-to-add-a-js-file-with-webpack/55270261#55270261)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok found answer myself. No special adjustments are necessary. Only include external file in code with relative path:

In my case:

```
import zepto from './../bower_components/zepto/zepto.js';
```

Comment: Thx there is no info on how to do this. in my case i had to import sha512 with this:  import sha512 from './../../../../../../node_modules/js-sha512/src/sha512'

Comment: Just wanted to mention this did work: `import 'nodePackage/subFolder/my-js-file.js';`

Comment: Which file should this import be included in?

Comment: Its quite a long time I used it. Afaik ''./entry.js" or any js file imported from "/entry"