# How to add a js file with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I was reading this webpack tutorial:

https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage.html

It says it bundles the src files and node_modules. If I want to add another .js file there, how can I do this? This is a thirdpartyjs file that is not part of the source and not part of the node_modules files. This is my current webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './app/app.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        filename: "dist.js",
        sourceMapFilename: "dist.map"
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
            }
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true
    },
    node: {
        fs: "empty"
    },
    watch: false
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include external file with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964886/how-to-include-external-file-with-webpack)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The start point for code is the `entry` field in config. In your config entry point is the list of files. Webpack gets all, resolve their dependencies and output in one file.

You have two options for adding third party script:

- add the file path to entry list before app.js
- require this file from app.js

Answer (score 1):

In response to Dmitry's answer:

> - add the file path to entry list before app.js

This has the effect that you will get a bundled .js file for each entry point, which you might not want.

> - require this file from app.js

You might not have access to `app.js` if it is written dynamically, or for whatever reason you might not want to edit `app.js`.

## Another option:

You can use [webpack-inject-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-inject-plugin) to inject any JS code as string into the resulting .js bundle created by webpack. This way you can read the File you want to inject as a string (e.g. `fs.readFile` in nodejs) and inject it with the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution but without using any extra plugins:

```
//Webpack.config.js
entry: {
  main: './src/index',
 /**
 /* object is passed to load script at global scope and exec immediately
 /* but if you don't need then simply do:
 /* myCustomScriptEntry: './src/myCustomScript'
 */
  myCustomScriptEntry: { 
    import: './src/myCustomScript',
    library: {
      name: 'myCustomScriptEntry',
      type: 'var',
    },
  },
},
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './public/index.html',
  excludeChunks: ['myCustomScriptEntry'], //exclude it from being autoreferenced in script tag
  favicon: './public/favicon.svg',
  title: 'Alida',
}),
```

and

```
//index.html
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= compilation.namedChunks.get('myCustomScriptEntry').files[0] %>"></script>
```