# How to solve TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).faceDetection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a face detection library. I have linked it in my index.html with script tag and want to use that file in my profile_pic component. On componentDidMount when I call the function it says that face_detection is not a function. When I used the same file with simple javascript it ran successfully. Now how do I use it with react?

I am getting the image from img tag and there is a file input control that is used to change the value of image dynamically.

This is my render method

```
 render() {

        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    marginTop: "20px",
                    display: "flex",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}
            >
                {/* div for upload photo  starts*/}
                <div>
                    <input
                        accept="image/*"
                        type="file"
                        id="image_upload"
                        style={{ display: "none" }}
                        onChange={e => {
                            this.handle_image_upload(e);
                        }}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="image_upload">
                        <img
                            id='picture'
                            src={this.state.image}
                            alt="Man or Woman"
                            style={{ width: "150px", height: "150px", cursor: "pointer" }}
                        />
                    </label>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
```

and here is the componentDidMount lifecycle method

```
componentDidMount() {

    document.getElementById("image_upload").addEventListener("change",()=>{this.face_detection()})
    }
```

This is the face_detection function

```
 face_detection=()=>{
        console.log($('#picture'))
        $('#picture').faceDetection({
                complete: function (faces) {
                        if (faces.length > 0) {
                                console.log('There is a face in this image')
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have successfully used the same library without react. Now how do I solve this error?

Comment: Why are you adding it as a script tag instead of bundling it in webpack? What does your import look like?

Comment: import statement only imports $ from jQuery and react from react. Is there any other file that should be imported?

Comment: If I import it directly in the component where I want to use the function it gives many errors which says "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression". It shows that these errors are originated from the library files

Answer (score 0):

It seems the library that provides 'faceDetection()' function is not defined. Related library should be defined in '`webpack.config.js`' or in one of js files of project using `'import'` or `'require'`. For example, below line imports 'myLibrary' (which locates inside 'libraries' dir) in your React component:

```
import * as myLibrary from '../libraries/myLibrary';
```

Now, 'faceDetection()' can be used like this:

```
myLibrary.faceDetection(...);
```

Comment: Where this library file should be located? Currently I have this library in a folder named face_detection which is in same directory as src folder. Should I move it somewhere else?

Comment: No, just put relative address of library in 'import' statement. For example, if your React component is in the root of 'src', your relative address will be './face_detection/<target>.js'.

Comment: face_detection is called using $('#picture') how do I do that using the imported object?

Comment: I can not import library because the library files are in the public folder. Any attempt to import them gives "Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.". Where should I move my files in this case?

Comment: Could you try moving 'face_detection' directory inside 'src' dir?
(There are other ways to include external js in webpack configuartion which are more complicated. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151194/how-to-add-a-js-file-with-webpack?rq=1 )